# error in code involving while loop and removing items from string

Tags: python, string, while-loop, tweepy

I have a code that downloads tweets and I am trying to sort through it labeling it as positive or negative each time i label a tweet I want to remove it from the string so I won't be asked to label it again here is my code so far

```
while True:
    if len(tweet_list) == 0:
        break
    else:
        tweet1= (np.random.choice(tweet_list))
        print tweet1
        judge = input("1 pos, 2 neg 3 skip: ")
        if judge == 1:
            tweet_pos.append(tweet1)
            tweet_list.remove(tweet1)
        if judge == 2:
            tweet_neg.append(tweet1)
            tweet_list.remove(tweet1)
```

after I label the second tweet I am given this error

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: You can't just remove something from a string - they're immutable. Also, don't name variables in a way that they shadow built-ins

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code aside from that you should compare judge to a string of `'1'` or `'2'` instead of a number, since input will always return string.

Comment: Your indentation needs to be fixed.

Comment: `input` is fine in this code, `raw_input` will return a string `'1'` though

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
newList = []
for myLetter in myList:
    if myLetter is not 'x':
        newList.append(myLetter)

newString = ''.join(newList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an empty list outside out of your while loop like this:

```
tweet_pos = []
tweet_neg = []
alreadySeen = []
```

Revise your first `if` statement in your code like so:

```
if len(alreadySeen) == 20:
        break
```

Make sure when you're displaying the tweets, you want to use `tweet1.text`. Sometimes it doesn't encode the message properly, or at all, so you can use `tweet1.text.encode('utf-8')`. Then each time you make a judgment, add that tweet to the `alreadySeen` list. Henceforth, check it to see if it is already in that list, and if it is, keep getting a random tweet until it hasn't already been seen.

```
if tweet1 not in alreadySeen:
        print tweet1.text.encode('utf-8')
        judge = input("1 pos, 2 neg, 3 skip: ")
        if judge == 1:
            tweet_pos.append(tweet1)
        elif judge == 2:
            tweet_neg.append(tweet1)
        alreadySeen.append(tweet1)
```

Finally, for confirmation, you can output the results by iterating through each tweet in `tweet_pos` and `tweet_neg` and print each tweet out just as you did earlier.

```
print "My positive tweets: "
for pos in tweet_pos:
    print pos.text.encode('utf-8')

print "My negative tweets: "
for neg in tweet_neg:
    print neg.text.encode('utf-8')
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: while True:
    if len(tweet_seen) == num:
        break
    tweet1= (np.random.choice(tweet_list))
    if tweet1 not in tweet_seen:
        print tweet1.text.encode
        judge = input("1 pos, 2 neg, 3 skip: ")
        if judge == 1:
            tweet_pos.append(tweet1)
        elif judge == 2:
            tweet_neg.append(tweet1)
        tweet_seen.append(tweet1)


print "My positive tweets: "
for pos in tweet_pos:
    print pos.text.encode('utf-8')

print "My negative tweets: "
for neg in tweet_neg:
    print neg.text.encode('utf-8')

Comment: getting this error     
AttributeError: 'numpy.string_' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Would you mind pasting your whole code in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) instead? That'll make it a lot easier to work with